# Firebase Auth and Unity3D - Unable to find FirebaseCppApp-5.1.1

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I've been building a game with Unity which I've hooked up to Firebases Auth and Database in order to store data and handle login and so far I've had no trouble with the project in the Unity Editor.

However, once I build for Android it seems like everything that has to do with Firebase is missing. So far I've tried changing the Android Manifest, updating play services, deleting and reimporting everything that has to do with Firebase.

This is where I Initialize Firebase:

```
public class FirebaseLogin : MonoBehaviour {

    public InputField emailField;
    public InputField passwordField;

    protected FirebaseAuth auth;
    private FirebaseAuth otherAuth;

    protected Dictionary<string, FirebaseUser> userByAuth = new Dictionary<string, FirebaseUser> ();

    DependencyStatus dependencyStatus = DependencyStatus.UnavailableOther;

        void Awake () {
        //So far my code runs this line
        DebugHelper.instance.Add ("Beginning");

        //When I try to debug the following line nothing happens, so it probably produces an error
        DebugHelper.instance.Add (FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.ToString ());

        FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync ().ContinueWith (task => {
            dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            if (dependencyStatus == DependencyStatus.Available) {
                InitializeFirebase ();
            } else {
                DebugHelper.instance.Add("Failed to initialize firebase");
                Debug.LogError("Failed");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I look at my logcat I'm getting the following error:

> Unable to find FirebaseCppApp-5.1.1
>
> E/Unity: DllNotFoundException: FirebaseCppApp-5.1.1  at (wrapper
>   managed-to-native)
>   Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper:SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_AppUtil(Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExc
>
> eptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate)
>
> at Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper..cctor () [0x00000] in
>   :0
>
> Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the
>   type initialize

I have been struggling to find an answer for this, but as far as I could tell no one has had the same issue.

Thanks in advance for taking the time to help!

Comment: It is better for you to start with samples https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity

Comment: Can you show us your `InitializeFirebase` method?

Comment: Hey again guys, after having done some thorough investigations and consulted with people smarter than I, it seems that I have narrowed down the issue.

The specific dlls or rather aar files I'm missing are:

play-services-base:15.0.1
firebase-common:16.0.0
firebase-core:16.0.1
firebase-app-unity:5.1.1
firebase-auth:16.0.2
firebase-auth-unity:5.1.1
firebase-database:16.0.1
firebase-database-unity:5.1.1
play-services-ads:15.0.1

I might have overlooked something somewhere, does any of you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who might have the same issue, here's how I solved it:

- I updated my android studios, twice apparently I was that far behind
- Then I installed the newest build tools SDK along with any google play service updates
- Then I updated the JDK, I was very far behind which made the PlayServicesResolver give me all sorts of errors
- I went back into unity, ran the PlayServicesResolver tools which fixed most of my issues
- Then I reimported the Unitypackages for Database and Auth

I believe this should be every step you need to solve this issue, however there might be a couple of problems with Android Manifests or the build gradle. I'm not entirely sure if it had an impact or not, but I added multiDexEnabled true to the build gradle. My Android Manifest underwent a lot of changes, but now that I look at it, I believe it's back to where it started when I first imported the Unitypackages

I hope my discoveries might help you, otherwise feel free to ask
Best of luck

Answer (score 2):

Posting an additional gotcha with this issue that may help others who land here.

I upgraded our project's Unity Firebase plugin from 5.4.2 to 5.4.3 and everything worked fine locally but our Jenkins build server would generate builds that failed with lots of these errors in logcat;

2019-02-14 10:52:53.183 21504-21551/? E/Unity: DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'FirebaseCppApp-5.4.2': The specified module could not be found.
     at Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE.PollCallbacks () [0x00000] in :0
     at Firebase.AppUtil.PollCallbacks () [0x00000] in :0
     at Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler.Update () [0x00000] in :0

The problem turned out to be that the Firebase .unitypackages gave files that did not change name between versions (eg. Firebase.App.dll or maven-metadata.xml) the same timestamp from version to version which caused svn to not see those files as changed and therefore not committing them to version control.

To solve this I simply touched all the Firebase files by going into Assets/Firebase and Assets/Plugins in terminal and running "find . -exec touch {} \;" (Mac). svn would then show the changed files.

If anyone from the Firebase Unity team reads this, may I request in future releases you update the timestamps on all files in the Firebase*.unitypackages to prevent version control systems (like svn) that use timestamp as a first pass change check ignoring the changes. Thanks!